# Как обнулить строку в input, которую я вывел через данный скрипт?

Tags: javascript, dom

Всем привет! Есть задача: Даны 2 инпута и кнопка. По нажатию на кнопку сгенерируйте случайную строку из символов и запишите ее в первый инпут. Длина случайной строки задается во втором инпуте.

Скрипт работает, НО допустим когда я задаю длину 10 символов, а потом например длину задаю 5 символов, меняются только первые 5 символов и  не исчезают остальные 5 последующих, которые были сгенерированы ранее. Пытался обнулить input.value = ''; не помогает. Подскажите кто знает!

```
<input class="input" type="text">
<input class="inputLength" type="text">
<button class="button">Запустить</button>

    var input = document.querySelector('.input');
    var inputLength = document.querySelector('.inputLength');
    var btn = document.querySelector('.button');
    let arr = [];
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < (Number(inputLength.value)); i++ ) {
            arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(getRandomIntInclusive(33, 126));
        }
        input.value = arr.join('');
    });
    console.log(arr);

    function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('.input');
var inputLength = document.querySelector('.inputLength');
var btn = document.querySelector('.button');
let arr = [];
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < (Number(inputLength.value)); i++) {
    arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(getRandomIntInclusive(33, 126));
  }
  input.value = arr.join('');
});
console.log(arr);

function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text">
<input class="inputLength" type="text">
<button class="button">Запустить</button>
```

Comment: Блин, точно массив надо было обнулить! Спасибо! Мне аж стыдно, немножко!

Comment: @МирасТекесбаев, желаю успехов!